# Como forzar a que el contenido de un th siempre se mantenga en linea

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Estoy usando Livewire e hice un header con un icono de **sort y direction** el problema es que cuando el tamaño de la pantalla se reduce el icono se mueve abajo del texto, me gustaria que se mantenga a un costado del texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@foreach ($headers as $field)
<th wire:click="order('{{ $field->field }}')">
    <span class="label">{{ $field->name }}</span>
    @if ($sort == '{{ $field->field }}')
        @if ($direction == 'asc')
            <i class="fal fa-sort-alpha-up-alt icon-sort"> </i>
        @else
            <i class="fal fa-sort-alpha-down-alt icon-sort"> </i>
        @endif
    @else
        <i class="fal fa-sort icon-sort"> </i>
    @endif
</th>
@endforeach


thead{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Nunito',sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
}
thead tr th, tbody tr td{
    padding: 7px 20px 7px 0px;
}
thead tr th{
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
thead tr th span{
    display: inline-block;
}
thead tr th i{
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo debes agregarle la propiedad **white-space:nowrap** que evita que se haga un salto de linea por espacio cuando el texto sea demaciado ancho.

```
tbody tr td{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: you are god? <3